# Pandas make comma separated key value output into a tabular form

Tags: python, pandas

I have below output which is a kind of comma separated Key value pair, list where i want all the `key` to become `Column Name` and `values` will become column values, i am wondering if this can be done in pandas.

```
Hostname: dpc8584.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
Hostname: dpc8585.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
Hostname: dpc8586.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
Hostname: dpc8587.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
Hostname: dpc8588.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
Hostname: dpc8589.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
Hostname: dpc8590.test.domain.com, bond0: OK (up), Active Slave: ens3f0, PriSlave: ens3f0 (up), SecSlave: ens3f1 (up), LFCPriInt:  0, LFCSecInt:  0
```

**My expected output will be:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by you have this 'output'? Is this already some print output of some object or is this just the beginning of some file you have, etc.?

Comment: @GWD, sorry for the confusion, its printed output indeed obtained from a tootset.

Comment: so what (object) have you printed there? tootset?

Comment: This is a simple text output captured on a file as i pasted.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**my approach**

You need read your`.csv` or `.txt` file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/textfile.csv',header=None)

                                   0                1                      2  \
0  Hostname: dpc8584.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   
1  Hostname: dpc8585.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   
2  Hostname: dpc8586.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   
3  Hostname: dpc8587.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   
4  Hostname: dpc8588.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   
5  Hostname: dpc8589.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   
6  Hostname: dpc8590.test.domain.com   bond0: OK (up)   Active Slave: ens3f0   

                        3                       4               5  \
0   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   
1   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   
2   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   
3   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   
4   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   
5   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   
6   PriSlave: ens3f0 (up)   SecSlave: ens3f1 (up)   LFCPriInt:  0   

                6  
0   LFCSecInt:  0  
1   LFCSecInt:  0  
2   LFCSecInt:  0  
3   LFCSecInt:  0  
4   LFCSecInt:  0  
5   LFCSecInt:  0  
6   LFCSecInt:  0
```

---

Then we can do:

```
df2 = df.stack().str.split(':',expand=True)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={0:'columns'}) #neccesary here
new_df = df2.pivot_table(index=df2.index.get_level_values(0),
                         columns='columns',
                         values=1,
                         aggfunc='first')
print(new_df)
```

---

```
columns  Active Slave  LFCPriInt  LFCSecInt      PriSlave      SecSlave  \
0              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   
1              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   
2              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   
3              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   
4              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   
5              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   
6              ens3f0          0          0   ens3f0 (up)   ens3f1 (up)   

columns     bond0                  Hostname  
0         OK (up)   dpc8584.test.domain.com  
1         OK (up)   dpc8585.test.domain.com  
2         OK (up)   dpc8586.test.domain.com  
3         OK (up)   dpc8587.test.domain.com  
4         OK (up)   dpc8588.test.domain.com  
5         OK (up)   dpc8589.test.domain.com  
6         OK (up)   dpc8590.test.domain.com
```

Comment: thnx @ansev, can we take `Hostname` column as the First column rather than lst one. already +1 for the solution..

Comment: yes, you can use : `new_df = new_df.reindex(columns = ['Hostname']+new_df.columns[:-1].tolist())`

Comment: you can enter a list with the order you want `new_df = new_df.reindex(columns = [your order labels])`

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

With a txt looking like this...

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('log_to_df.txt', header=None)
df
```

[image]

```
pattern = re.compile(r'((.+?): )(.+)')
cols = []
for col in df.columns:
    temp = pattern.match(df[col][0])
    cols.append(temp[2])
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(temp[1], '', regex=True)
df.columns = cols
df
```

[image]

If the column headers change just tweak the line with the regex in it...

```
((.+?): )(.+)')
```

...to match something else